# Automated dismounting & mounting of external hard drive

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, script

I have an external hard drive for my backups, but to better protect it against ransomware, I want to have a scheduled script after the backup finishes, that dismounts the drive, and then a similar one to mount the drive just before the backup initiates.

I've tried some PowerShell scripts with DriveEject but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Most backup software have an auto-eject build in. For example Veeam has this. What are you using for a backup?

Comment: protect it against ransomware,  .........  If the drive is plugged in and ejected in a soft sense, ransomware can still jump into the drive.  So you need to physically unplug the drive.